# XML Parser and xpath expression

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am using java default documentbuilder to parse a xml document which has less than 100 lines of code . It will take 35 milliseconds to parse a document , a single xpath expression takes 15 milliseconds to execute  . How can I optimize the time taken for both xml and parser? .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class XMLParser {


    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(XMLParser.class.getName());

    private Map<String,List<NamedNodeMap>> fileVsProperties = new HashMap<String, List<NamedNodeMap>>();

    private Document document;

    public XMLParser(File file){
            this.document = XMLUtil.getDocument(file);
    }

    public void setProperties(Element file){
        NodeList properties = file.getElementsByTagName("property");
        List<NamedNodeMap> props = new ArrayList<NamedNodeMap>();
        String type = file.getAttribute("type");
        String path = file.getAttribute("path");

        if("".equals(path)){
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"Attribute path is required for a file.");
            return;
        }

        path = path+":"+type;

        for(int i = 0;i<properties.getLength();i++){
            Element property = (Element) properties.item(i);
            props.add(property.getAttributes());
        }
        setProperties(props,path);
    }

    private void setProperties(List<NamedNodeMap> properties , String path){
        List<NamedNodeMap>  previousValue = fileVsProperties.get(path);
        if(previousValue != null){
            previousValue.addAll(properties);
        }else{
            fileVsProperties.put(path,properties);
        }

    }

    public Element getConfiguration(String branchName) throws XPathExpressionException{
        return (Element)XMLUtil.getElements("/configurations/configuration[@name='"+branchName+"']",document.getDocumentElement(),XPathConstants.NODE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File doc = new File("install.xml");
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(doc);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Taken For Parsing :: "+ (end-start) + " milliseconds");
        start = end;
        Element configuration = parser.getConfiguration("BHARATHIKANNAN");
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Taken For XPATH Expression TO Finding the Configuration :: "+ (end-start) + " milliseconds");
        start = end;
        NodeList files = parser.getFiles(configuration);
        for(int i=0;i<files.getLength();i++){
            parser.setProperties((Element) files.item(i));
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(parser.fileVsProperties);
        System.out.println("Time Taken For Setting Properties :: "+ (end-start) + " milliseconds");
    }

    public NodeList getFiles(Element configuration){
        return configuration.getElementsByTagName("file");
    }

}


class XMLUtil{
    private static DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    private static DocumentBuilder builder;
    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(XMLUtil.class.getName());

    private static XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    private static XPath xpath;

    static {

        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"");
        }
    }

    public static Document getDocument(File f){
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = builder.parse(f);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING,"Invalid XML Document ",e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,"No Document Found in the given path",e);
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public static Object getElements(String xpathExpression , Element ele ,QName dataType) throws XPathExpressionException{
        return xpath.evaluate(xpathExpression, ele,dataType);
    }


}
```

XML File

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
        Note : Default configuration loaded using your current branch name . You can extend configurations using extend attribute in configuration
        node . 
-->
<configurations>
        <configuration name="default">
                <files>
                        <file type="xml" path="conf/server.xml.orig">
                                <property regex="(port=).*" replace="\18080" xpath="/Server/Connector"></property>
                                <property regex="(port=).*" replace="\18080"></property>
                        </file>
                        <file type="text" path="conf/system_properties.conf">
                                <property regex="(username=).*" replace="\1root" ></property>
                        </file>
                </files>
        </configuration>
        <configuration name="BHARATHIKANNAN" extends="default">
                <files>
                        <file type="text" path="conf/system_properties.conf">
                                <property regex="(username=).*" replace="\1root" ></property>
                        </file>
                </files>
        </configuration>
</configurations>
```

Output :

```
Time Taken For Parsing :: 24 milliseconds
Time Taken For XPATH Expression TO Finding the Configuration :: 14 milliseconds
{conf/system_properties.conf:text=[com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttributeMap@75d9fd51]}
Time Taken For Setting Properties :: 0 milliseconds
```

Comment: You state 35s in your question, but your log states 24ms.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hm, the output does not show seconds, but milliseconds! 24 and 14 milliseconds seemn to be ok.

Comment: If it's really about ms, why do you want to further optimize it? Performance seems fine to me!

Comment: @DavidGrant,@home yeah , typo in my question I changed to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked recently about a very similar task but with a much larger document (2Mb), and I gave some Saxon timings here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497928/xpath-speed-comparision/12508614#12508614

These timings are much faster than you are seeing, on a much larger document. Since you are already using Java, switching to Saxon should be very straightforward.

One caveat though is that you start your timings immediately on entry to main() which means you are mainly measuring class loading time rather than XML processing time. My measurements took care to warm up the Java VM before measurement started.

Note that if you're using Saxon, it's best by far to use Saxon's native tree model rather than DOM or other alternatives. We recently published some measurements here:

http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2012/09/index.html#000194

DOM comes out 8 times worse than Saxon's native tree on average, 23 times worse in the worst case.